# Two languages, two apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization

I am developing an App that relies heavily in videos stored inside the App (not streamed). Our intention is to release it in spanish and english.

I know the way to go with Apps is to create just one multilingual version with localized strings and XIBs. But because the videos need to be in both languages, if we release just one version the App would be twice as heavy (120 megabytes instead of 60).

Is it OK for itunes and the store to add two versions of the App in different languages in the sake of not releasing a very large Application? Does someone know of any problems this might generate?

Answer (score 2):

You should absolutely be able to release two applications, with different languages being their only difference. If you were selling dictionary apps, different languages should very much be different apps.

Comment: The biggest drawback in having two apps instead of one is that your app ratings will be lower since the number of downloads will be split between the two apps rather than combined. But  with such a large difference in file size, the trade off may be worthwhile, especially to your users.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it's a good idea for these to be separate apps for the reasons you mention.  In your project though these can be two separate app definitions within the same project, having two different targets.  You do not have to have two different projects.