# How to build two targets for two language in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This question is almost the same as [Two languages, two apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655530/two-languages-two-apps), but as the question and its answer both originated in 2011, I'm here to ask again.

I know the way to use `Localization` for different languages, but my situation is a little different. I have a large dictionary file in my App, for each language it's different. Besides that, everything is the same, the logic, the UI.

Is there any better idea than building a new app for each language?

Comment: Are you trying to localize the stored dictionary file or just texts across the app?
In both cases, you can get device's locale settings from `Locale`.
Preferred languages for example with `Locale.preferredLanguages`, or country code with `Locale.current.regionCode`.
Once the user's locale has been determined, and you have some sort of a backend, you can store localized texts in a database, fetch them once (if they're not bound to change) on app launch as well as the dictionary file, store locally, and spread texts across views.

Comment: @Art The former. It's a great idea for using local text to ask for a request and the backend infer which data file should it offers.  But it's not friendly for app that has no backend.